# PHP ereg_replace deprecated

Tags: php, deprecated, ereg-replace

I have a script that throws me errors because I run PHP 5.3.1
What Do I have to use in the example?

```
$row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n", "\\n", $row[$j]);
```

**Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in..**

Comment: I was searching for script to backup my mysql database and found this [http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php](http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php) article and then I found this post which is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) instead, just add [delimiters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter).

```
$row[$j] = preg_replace("#\n#", "\\n", $row[$j]);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the delimiters, and that they don't have to be forward slashes.

Comment: Did you miss an 's' at the end of the pattern? Doesn't ereg_replace implicitly behave like an "/s" at the end.

Comment: @BasilMusa I do not know, everything I have converted I did not require an `s` at the end. From what I remember of `ereg_replace` was that it just omitted the delimiters, but it is possible it also did an `s` as well. Really just depends on the regex I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function instead.